# Correct way to use git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, repository

I decided to use GIT when developing a rails application.  When i code i started off my initial commit on my master branch which i set as a slate to work off of. Then when i want to add a new feature such as devise i would checkout a new branch called "devise" then start coding on that branch. When i feel that everything is working fine with my devise implementation i merge the devise branch onto the master branch and push the master to heroku. Am i doing all this the right way or should i structure my code another way thats more efficient?

Comment: Stack Overflow works best when you ask specific, technical questions. "is this the right way" questions are not really the intended kind, as they are opinion based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at a very very good starting point here. With a feature branch you can effectively work on the new feature even when you need/want to fix a bug on the main branch. Even if you decide to stop your feature your partially done work is in a safe place and master stays 
clean. I would call this well done.

Later when the day comes to support multiple releases then you still can evolve the branch model. You'll find some suggestions like [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Updated:
Supposed you checked out the feature branch, then invoke **git merge main**. In the post that I referenced these operations are shown as arrows between the branches (which are shown vertically). For more help on merges invoke the help: **git help merge**. You may need to try this out in a test repository to understand how it works, it needs practical experience to know when best to merge.

Note that if you changed the files also on the feature branch you may need to manually modify the result since git cannot resolve all changes automatically (nor another source control systems).

Comment: Thank you for this, now if im working on my feature and i fix a bug on the main branch will that bug fix be made on the feature branch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a good idea to do feature development on feature branches, and your proposed workflow sounds fine.

Please be advised though that there are many possible workflows with git and asking if one particular branching model is the "right way" is to open a can of worms.  People can get [quite](http://www.jarrodspillers.com/2009/08/19/git-merge-vs-git-rebase-avoiding-rebase-hell/) [opinionated](http://www.derekgourlay.com/archives/428) [about](http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git) [this](http://senko.net/en/git-merge-rebase/).

So don't worry so much about doing it the "best" way.  If your workflow is working for you, then go with it.